# бесконечный запуск двух функций через разный интервал python

Tags: python

Есть функция main() которая запускается каждые 15 сек. и есть функция main2 которая должна запускаться раз в 600 сек, подскажите как реализовать независимую и параллельную работу двух этих функций, пробовал через

```
while True:
time.sleep(30)
main()
```

но если добавить вторую функцию, то работа будет последовательнй

Comment: А в питоне есть многопоточность?

Comment: Точно должна быть!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from functools import wraps
from threading import Timer

def periodic(delay):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            f(*args, **kwargs)
            Timer(delay, wrapper, args=args, kwargs=kwargs).start()
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@periodic(15)
def f1(msg):
    print(msg)

@periodic(600)
def f2(msg):
    print(msg.upper())


f1('test')
f2('proverka')
```

Comment: Благодарю, пойду тестировать

Comment: Ух, красиво. Лень гуглить, можешь сказать что такое wraps?

Comment: @NotStatilko декоратор копирующий метаданные декорируемой функции в функцию-обёртку.

Comment: @Non фразой "Ух, красиво. Лень гуглить, можешь сказать что такое wraps? Сидя на stackoverflow" - ты сделал мой день чуточку лучше)))