# Как написать периодически выполняемую функцию для бота?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, telegram-bot, telegram

Хочу добавить в telegram бота функцию, с помощью которой он сможет в определенное время раз в сутки отправлять пользователю какой-то текст, вот пример:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()      
today = now.day
hour = round(now.hour, 2)

while True:
    if today == now.day and (hour > 22.00 and hour < 23.00):
        bot.send_message(CHAT_ID, random.choice(welcomes))
        today += 1
    else:
        time.sleep(3600)
```

Этот код не работает, он полностью перекрывает весь остальной функционал. Подскажите , как можно реализовать такую цикличную функцию,или же исправить эту?

Comment: Можно в два потока. Но это конечно сложный способ на мой взгляд. Вообще, посмотрите в библиотеке, нет ли там таких функций для периодического повторения

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [бесконечный запуск двух функций через разный интервал python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/950453/%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте отдельный поток и в нем выполняйте ваш цикличный код:

```
from threading import Thread
import datetime
import time
import random


WELCOMES = [...]
CHAT_ID = ...


def schedule_loop(bot):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    hour = now.hour
    print('hour:', hour)

    while True:
        if hour in [22, 23]:
            bot.send_message(CHAT_ID, random.choice(WELCOMES))

        time.sleep(3600)


bot = ...

# Создаем новый поток и в нем запускаем нашу функцию:
Thread(target=schedule_loop, args=(bot,)).start()
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь! Подскажите , пожалуйста. А остальной код тоже в отдельный поток с помощью 'Thread'  оформить, или это не обязательно?

Comment: @AlekseiGrabor, не обязательно -- остальной код будет в главном потоке выполняться. Кст, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: а если этот код записать в другой файл, как его  запустить? Просто импортировать в основной файл?

Comment: @AlekseiGrabor, да, при импорте он выполнится (если не находится в `if __name__ == '__main__':`). А лучше код поместите в функцию и импортируйте функцию с ее вызовом -- результат будет тот же, но код станет очевиднее

Comment: все , понял, спасибо большое)