# telegram bot.infinity_polling прерывает работку скрипт python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Весь код который находится после строки

```
bot.infinity_polling(True)
```

не выполняется, а если поместить код самого бота в самый низ скрипта, а исполняемый код вверх, то перестает работать бот, подскажите как решить данную проблему

```
import telebot

TOKEN = ""
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет,\nДля изменения объема введи /volume\nДля изменения времени обновления введи /update')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['volume'])
def volume(message):
    sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи объем!')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, update_volume)

def update_volume(message):
    try:
        if(int(message.text)):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Твой объем обновлен на: {name}'.format(name=message.text))
            return message.text
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Попробуй еще, только на этот раз введи число /volume')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['update'])
def update(message):
    sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи интервал обновления в секундах!')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, get_update)

def get_update(message):
    try:
        if(int(message.text)):
            sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Интервал обновления изменен на: {name}'.format(name=message.text))
            # test(message.text)
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Попробуй еще, только на этот раз введи число /update')


bot.infinity_polling(True)


print('test')
```

Comment: Скорее всего вызов `infinity_polling` запускает цикл обработки событий бота и, соответственно, все что после цикла будет выполнено когда цикл закончится. Вот же код: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/e62eeb7ff2a6c23f2a30dff38b19d76d62e45eb3/telebot/__init__.py#L367

Comment: но это же бесконечный цикл

Comment: как уже ответили ниже - так и задумано что, после polling() ничего работать и не будет, так как это цикл, и выйдет из него бот в случае ошибки....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя [по коду](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/e62eeb7ff2a6c23f2a30dff38b19d76d62e45eb3/telebot/__init__.py#L367):

```
def infinity_polling(self, *args, **kwargs):
    while not self.__stop_polling.is_set():
        try:
            self.polling(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            time.sleep(5)
            pass
    logger.info("Break infinity polling")
```

Метод `infinity_polling` нужен только для обхода падения бота путем перезапуска его. [В обычной ситуации](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/e62eeb7ff2a6c23f2a30dff38b19d76d62e45eb3/examples/telebot_bot/telebot_bot.py#L84) вызывался бы `bot.polling`, внутри которого также крутился цикл.

Т.к. этот код вызывает цикл, то все остальные действия ниже него не произойдут пока цикл не завершится.

Если автору нужно параллельно что-то выполнить, то нужно запускать что-то в отдельном потоке, например самого бота -- через вызов `infinity_polling`.

Пример можно [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/951194/201445) посмотреть.

---

**PS.** могу предложить пример отправки той функции бота в поток (не тестировал):

```
from threading import Thread

...

# Создаем новый поток и в нем запускаем нашу функцию:
Thread(target=bot.infinity_polling, args=(True,)).start()
```

Тогда код после `Thread...` будет дальше выполняться.