# Телеграм бот перестаёт отвечать

Tags: python-3.x, telebot, heroku, threading

Всем привет! Создавал бота для телеграмма через pytelegrambotapi. Бот залит на heroku, параллельно боту работают ещё 4 потока. В определенный момент дня (часа в 2 дня по мск) перестаёт отвечать, хотя загружен в 3 утра. Я не реагирует ни на команды уже работающего с ним пользователя, ни на новых. При этом потоки продолжают работать и даже присылать сообщения (один из них раз в 2 часа присылает уведомления). Подскажите, молю, с чем это может быть связано

Comment: на Heroku оплачена аренда сервера? или на free аккаунте?

Comment: в общем у меня была подобная проблема на Heroku. По поискам и ответам на различных форумах, сначала, мне сказали, что это могло быть из-за бесплатного аккаунта, так как сервер который выделен для бесплатного варианта, со временем отрубает службы. 
но проблема повторилась вновь через некоторое время, уже на арендованном личном VPS на Ubuntu

Comment: ниже оставлю в ответах вариант, который мне помог. но пока прошло лишь несколько дней с этого варианта решения. может кому-то пригодится.

Comment: ну прошла почти неделя с моего решения. Бот не падал, не зависал.

Comment: посмотрел реальное время с последнего коммита, более 10 дней бот не зависает, отвечает быстро.

Comment: вы хотя бы в комменты дайте фидбэк или отметьте ответ, решение помогло или нет вам

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите логи на сервере, где размещается логика вашего бота. Если у вас похожая проблема попробуйте добавить вместо `bot.polling(none_stop=True)` добавить `bot.infinity_polling(timeout=10, long_polling_timeout = 5)`

Детальнее можно изучить тут: [Падает бот ГитХаб](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/1259) и тут: [Работа бота СтакОверфлоу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/953052/telegram-bot-infinity-polling-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-python)